# Reading half floats into array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have this binary file that stores half float values that I need to read into array.

```
00 BC 00 00 DD C4

Where the first two bytes represent = -1.,
3rd & 4th = 0.,
5th & 6th = -4.86328125,
```

I want to read them into array that looks like this, {-1.000000, 0.000031, -4.863281}

Any clues of how to do this?

Ps. I know that C# does not deal with half floats directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following library, it implements a `Half` class to support half floats.

http://sourceforge.net/p/csharp-half/code/HEAD/tree/

Usage: (btw, the 2nd number is 0 not 0.000031)

```
        byte[] array = new byte[]{
            0x00, 0xBC, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDD, 0xC4
        };

        Half h1 = Half.ToHalf(array, 0);
        Half h2 = Half.ToHalf(array, 2);
        Half h3 = Half.ToHalf(array, 4);

        float f1 = (float)h1;
        float f2 = (float)h2;
        float f3 = (float)h3;

        Console.WriteLine("h1 = {0}; f1 = {1}", h1, f1);
        Console.WriteLine("h2 = {0}; f2 = {1}", h2, f2);
        Console.WriteLine("h3 = {0}; f3 = {1}", h3, f3);

        /* outputs
         * 
         * h1 = -1; f1 = -1
         * h2 = 0; f2 = 0
         * h3 = -4.863281; f3 = -4.863281
         * 
         */
```

**EDIT:**
Use cast from Half to float.